# Where are the Mysterious Relics?

Tags: achievements, lord-of-the-rings-online

I was running around Evendim and I found an angry hobbit who apparently got his prize pipeweed crops destroyed by a Mysterious Relic that gives +1 Dread to anyone who comes near. When I right-click it, I got a quest to talk to that angry hobbit, who complained, and then I got a new deed, which told me to find all 7. Where are these?

Comment: Aw, _four...more...rep...points..._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds a lot like the Mysterious Relics deed, but there's only 5 [mysterious relics](http://lorebook.lotro.com/wiki/Mysterious_Relics) (linked page has detailed maps to each one):

- Famine
- Death
- War
- Pestilence
- Purest Evil

> Mysterious Relics is a deed gained from finding each of the five mysterious relics, gaining the delivery quest from each one, and completing them. The reward is the title, "The Calm Before the Storm". While you're tagging the relics, you might want to go tag the related instances as well, as explained on the In Their Absence page.

Each one also corresponds to a different Gaunt Lord, in the related deed [In Their Absence](http://lorebook.lotro.com/wiki/In_Their_Absence), although the two deeds are not otherwise related.